# Firebase transaction not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am calling from an angular app, using angularfire2, `this.afDb.database` is the db instance

```
const downloadsRef = this.afDb.database.ref('research_reports-published/' + rrid + '/' + field);
downloadsRef.transaction(function(fieldval) {
  if (fieldval) {
    fieldval = fieldval + 1;
  }
  return fieldval;
},
function(error, committed, snapshot) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
  } else if (!committed) {
    console.log('We aborted the transaction (because ada already exists).');
  } else {
    console.log('User ada added!');
  }
  console.log('Adas data: ', snapshot.val());
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
});
```

The code just silently prints

```
Adas data: oldvalue 
Transaction successfully committed
```

and exits

Comment: What's wrong with the behavior you see?

Comment: nothing gets updated. I was expecting a db query in backend incrementing `'research_reports-published/' + rrid + '/' + field`

Comment: Use the [parameters that are passed into your `then()` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction), which *might* give a hint.

Comment: I added the second callback , it prints `Adas data:  oldvalue`, what do I make of this?

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code and output. But note that you don't have to add an extra callback, `committed` and `snapshot` are already passed into the `then()` callback you have. In fact, I'm not even sure if you can both pass the callback and use the promise. I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue in above code. It should be

```
if (fieldval != null) {
  fieldval = fieldval + 1;
}
```

as fieldval=0 also makes it false